# Passing the url in a link not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass the id of a blogpost in an url. It works in the adminpanel (read blogpost) now I want to do the same on my frontpage, so that it says read more under every blogpost, but when I use the same code it doesn'nt pass the id.

My code that isn't working:

```
$db_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')or die("cannot connect"); 
        mysql_select_db('database',$conn);
// mysql query         

    $sql_query="SELECT * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC";


// Create the ps_pagination object here
    $pager = new ps_pagination($db_connection,$sql_query,5,5);   
        echo $pager->renderFullNav();

//The paginate() function returns a mysql result set   
    $rs = $pager->paginate();   
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {   

// table to display results here // modify here 
    echo '<h1>'.$rows["title"].'</p></h1>';
    echo '<p> '.$rows["post"].'</p>';
    echo '<p class="klein"><span>Door</span>: '.$rows["first_name"].' ';
    echo '<p class="klein">Geplaatst op</span>: '.$rows["date_posted"].'</p>';
    echo "<td><a class='link' href=\"/admin/bekijk.php?id=$row->id\">Lees meer</a></td>";                
    echo "<BR>";
}   
// close mysql connection here
  mysql_close();
```

My code that is working:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) 
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<h1><td><a class='link' href=\"bekijk.php?id=$row->id\">$row->title</a></td></h1>";
        if($row->id == 0)
        { //home page verberg delete link
        } 
        else 
        {
            // delete functie waarbij een alert word weergegeven of je dit zeker wil
            echo "<td><a class='link' href=\"javascript:delpage('$row->id','$row->title');\">Verwijder</a></td>";
            echo '<br>';
            echo "<td><a class='link' href=\"edit.php?id=$row->id\">Pas aan</a></td>";
            echo '<br>';
            echo "<td><a class='link' href=\"bekijk.php?id=$row->id\">Bekijk</a></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

They both link to this page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../includes/includes.php';
require('../includes/functions.php'); 
//make sure user is logged in, function will redirect use if not logged in
login_required();

//if logout has been clicked run the logout function which will destroy any active sessions and redirect to the login page
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    logout();
}
?>

<html>
<title>Admin</title>
<script src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<header><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"></header>


<body>
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="../index.php" target=_blank"">Bekijk site</a></li>
    <li><a href="voegtoe.php">Toevoegen</a></li>
    <li><a href="verwijder.php">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?logout">Uitloggen</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
<?php
//pak het ID van de pagina die aangepast moet worden
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_object($q);
?>


<div id="bekijkwrap">
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" />
<h1><?php echo $row->title;?></h1>
<p><?php echo $row->post;?></p>
</form>



</div>
```

Comment: Please check this line - echo "<td><a class='link' href=\"/admin/bekijk.php?id=$row->id\">Lees meer</a></td>";  Need to write '$rows->id'

Comment: Yeah I know that line is not working, but it is the same as the other, and that one does work. So I have no clue why this one is not working.

Comment: Please write $rows->id instead of $row->id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your broken code loops through [mysql_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc), setting your `$rows` variable as an (associative) array for each iteration.

Your working code calls [mysql_fetch_object()](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_object), pulling back an object (of class StdClass) for each iteration.

Your broken code attempts to reference the id by treating the `$row` variable as if it was an object. Not only does this variable not exist (it should be `$rows`), but the `$rows` variable is an associative array, not an object.

Therefore, instead of accessing the value using the syntax `$foo->id`, it must be accessed like `$foo['id']` instead.

To fix the problem, change:

```
echo "<td><a class='link' href=\"/admin/bekijk.php?id=$row->id\">Lees meer</a>
```

To

```
echo "<td><a class='link' href=\"/admin/bekijk.php?id=" . $rows['id'] . "\">Lees meer</a>
```

You can see in the lines above that in your original code that you're referencing `$rows` and treating it like an array. This is what you must do to the problem line too.